# How do I select items from a table where a single column must contain two (or more) values?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL database table that references different words and their locations in documents. I want to return the IDs of documents that contain all of the words.

Here is an example table.

```
docid     wordid
1         4
2         4
1         2
1         5
```

Ok, now say that someone queried the database for the words that had WORDIDs 4, 2, and 5.

My erroneous SQL SELECT statement would be something like:

```
Select docid from table where wordid = 4 and wordid = 2 and wordid = 5
```

This is giving me 0 results.

I [have seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594343/how-do-i-select-multiple-values-in-the-same-column) in other places where the `where in` clause has been suggested:

If I understand correctly, this is another way to write an OR clause. I have tried this:

```
select docid from table where wordid in (4,2,5)
```

But, this is giving me all the results. It should exclude docid 2 as that does not contain the other words. I'm expecting to just get docid 1.

However, I could be using the `where in` clause incorrectly as I have very little db experience.

How can I return docids that contain all of the words?

Please note as well, my where clause will be dynamically generated in a FOR loop.  The query could be as simple as one or two words, or it could be 10 or 12 words. I'm looking for a query structure that takes speed into consideration. Please let me know if you need anymore information.

For reference, I am trying to convert this code into PHP / MYSQL, but I don't understand the sql statement here or its equivalent in MYSQL:

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/9780596529321/4dot-searching-and-ranking/querying

Comment: Is there a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(docid, wordid)`?

Comment: @ypercube no, there is no unique constraint. A document (docid) can have any number of words. Each word in the document is represented by its wordid. Basically, it's an index of what words appear in what documents. If a document had 100 words, then its id would appear 100 times in this database.

Comment: OK, but can you have 2 rows with same `docid` **and** same `wordid`?

Comment: @ypercube honestly, I am not quite sure, but my gut tells me that 'wordid' in this table is unique. There is another table that contains 'docid, wordid, wordlocation' where the wordlocation is the position of the word in the text. Maybe this will shed some light on the topic for you, for anyone, who would like to know where this is going: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/9780596529321/4dot-searching-and-ranking/querying  I'm trying to reproduce this code in PHP / MYSQL but I'm not sure how to recreate the SQL statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the **[relational division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)** problem and there is a question about it at SO, with a lot of ways to write this query, plus performance analysis for PostgreSQL: **[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)**

Shamelessly copying code form there and removing/changing code for answers that have features lacking from MySQL, like CTEs, `EXCEPT`, `INTERSECT`, etc, here are a few ways to do this.

Assumptions:

- the table is called `factors`
- there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(wordid, docid)`
- there is a `documents` and a `words` table:

Easy to write, medium efficiency:

```
-- Query 1 -- by Martin
SELECT d.docid, d.docname
FROM   document d
JOIN   factors f USING (docid)
WHERE  f.wordid IN (2, 4, 5)
GROUP  BY d.docid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 ;           -- number of words
```

Easy to write, medium efficiency:

```
-- Query 2 -- by Erwin
SELECT d.docid, d.docname
FROM   documents d
JOIN   (
   SELECT docid
   FROM   factors
   WHERE  wordid IN (2, 4, 5)
   GROUP  BY docid
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
   ) f USING (docid) ;
```

More complex to write, very good efficiency in Postgres - probably lousy in MySQL:

```
-- Query 4 -- by Derek
SELECT d.docid, d.docname
FROM   documents d
WHERE  d.docid IN (SELECT docid FROM factors WHERE wordid = 2)
AND    d.docid IN (SELECT docid FROM factors WHERE wordid = 4);
AND    d.docid IN (SELECT docid FROM factors WHERE wordid = 5);
```

More complex to write, very good efficiency in Postgres - and probably the same in MySQL:

```
-- Query 5 -- by Erwin
SELECT d.docid, d.docname
FROM   documents d
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM factors 
               WHERE  docid = d.docid AND wordid = 2)
AND    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM factors 
               WHERE  docid = d.docid AND wordid = 4)
AND    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM factors 
               WHERE  docid = d.docid AND wordid = 5) ;
```

More complex to write, very good efficiency in Postgres - and probably the same in MySQL:

```
-- Query 6 -- by Sean
SELECT d.docid, d.docname
FROM   documents d
JOIN   factors x ON d.docid = x.docid
JOIN   factors y ON d.docid = y.docid
JOIN   factors z ON d.docid = z.docid
WHERE  x.wordid = 2
AND    y.wordid = 4
AND    z.wordid = 5 ;
```

Easy to write and extend to an arbitrary set of `words` but not as efficient as the `JOIN` and `EXISTS` solutions:

```
-- Query 7 -- by ypercube
SELECT d.docid, d.docname
FROM   documents d
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   words AS w 
   WHERE  w.wordid IN (2, 4, 5)
   AND    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM   factors AS f 
      WHERE  f.docid = d.docid 
      AND    f.wordid = w.wordid 
      )
   );
```

Easy to write, not good efficiency:

```
-- Query 8 -- by ypercube
SELECT d.docid, d.docname
FROM   documents d
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM  (
      SELECT 2 AS wordid UNION  ALL
      SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5
      ) AS w
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM   factors AS f 
      WHERE  f.docid = d.docid 
      AND    f.wordid = w.wordid 
      )
   );
```

Enjoy testing them :)