# Select on several {name,value} pairs

Tags: mysql

I have a this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Pairs(
   id    VARCHAR(8)  NOT NULL
   ,name  VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
   ,value VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
   ,PRIMARY KEY (id,name));
```

I want to write a query to retrieve the `id` which is present in several rows with several constraints on `name` and `value` like:

- `name like 'forname%' AND value like 'CAMI%'`
- `name like 'projet%'  AND value like '%gociation'`
- `name ... AND  value ...`
- ...

The cardinality of the constraints is unknown at compile time, it comes from a GUI.

I wrote this query:

```
select * from (
      SELECT * FROM Pairs WHERE ( name   =  'projet'   ) AND ( value like '%gociation' )
union SELECT * FROM Pairs WHERE ( name like 'forname%' ) AND ( value like 'CAMI%' )
) as u order by id
```

the result is:

```
id      name    value
AEMIMA  projet  renegociation
AENABE  projet  renegociation
AEREDH  projet  renegociation
AGOGLY  projet  renegociation
AHOGAL  projet  renegociation
AHSPID  projet  renegociation       <<<<<<<<<<<<
AHSPID  fornameE    CAMILLE         <<<<<<<<<<<<
AIOSAP  projet  renegociation
AIPNEU  projet  renegociation
```

Only the `<<<<<<<<<<<<` marked lines are good and the id I want is `AHSPID`.

How can I eliminate the lines which doesn't match **ALL** the constraints?

Comment: For a start, which RDBMS?

Comment: MySql, but it's a pure-SQL question, I presume.

Comment: Similar to this problem: [How do I select items from a table where a single column must contain two (or more) values?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45512/how-do-i-select-items-from-a-table-where-a-single-column-must-contain-two-or-mo)

Answer (score 2):

I've found answer around `Key/Value pairs` terms, and the capacity involved is the inner-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   Prospects.id,
   Prospects.prenom,
   Prospects.nom,
   Prospects.date,
   Prospects.departement
FROM
    Prospects
    INNER JOIN Pairs AS p1 ON Prospects.id = p1.id
    INNER JOIN Pairs AS p2 ON Prospects.id = p2.id
    INNER JOIN Pairs AS p3 ON Prospects.id = p3.id
    INNER JOIN Pairs AS p4 ON Prospects.id = p4.id
    INNER JOIN Pairs AS p5 ON Prospects.id = p5.id
    INNER JOIN Pairs AS p6 ON Prospects.id = p6.id
WHERE TRUE
AND (( p1.name like 'name%'    ) AND ( p1.value LIKE '%XXX%')) 
AND (( p2.name like 'forname%' ) AND ( p2.value LIKE '%CAMILLE%')) 
AND (( p3.name = 'codePostal'  ) AND ( p3.value = 'XXXXX')) 
AND (( p4.name = 'email'       ) AND ( p4.value LIKE '%XXXX%' )) 
AND (( p5.name like 'tel_%'    ) AND ( p5.value LIKE '%XXXXXX%')) 
AND (( p6.name = 'projet'      ) AND ( p6.value LIKE '%gociat%' ))
AND ( etape IN (-1,3,8 ))
```

The lines `INNER JOIN...id` and `AND (( p... ))` are generated by analysis of the request dynamically made by the GUI. The keyword `TRUE` is added to make all `AND...` lines identical, the first isn't different from the others.

Comment: Yep, inner joins are the answer to determining the links between different rows of data.

Comment: Really, the various `( Prospects.id = p1.id )` conditions should be at `ON` clauses and not in the `WHERE` clause. No matter if MySQL allows such non-standard syntax, every `INNER JOIN` should be coupled with an `ON`.