# Compare two sets with a quantity field

Tags: mysql

Imagine I have a basket from an online shop, with id of item and the quantity.
I have a list of items of quantity and I would like to find a basket with the exact same items and quantity for each.

I have found solutions to find matching sets, but not with duplicates or quantity field.

The basket could contain multiple times the same item id, or I could also choose to have a quantity field, depending on what's better

thanks

two solutions I see for database format :

```
id_basket id_product quantity
1           1           2
1           2           1
2           1           2
2           2           1
3           1           1
3           2           1
```

or

```
id_basket id_product 
1           1
1           1
1           2       
2           1
2           1       
2           2  
3           1
3           2
```

basket 1 and 2 contain the same thing, but not the third, and I would like to be able to find a basket that contains a list of product using "raw" data, so the idea is not to find duplicates on the database, but find one that matches a static list (like find a basket that contain 2x item 1 and 1x item 2)

Comment: Show the solution you've found and what is exactly the problem with adding quantity to comparing sets.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45512/how-do-i-select-items-from-a-table-where-a-single-column-must-contain-two-or-mo/45516#45516 "there is a UNIQUE constraint on (wordid, docid)"

Comment: In MySql fist have baskets totals and basket-item subtotals . Then do triangle self  join of baskets by equal totals and intesect basket's items subtotals. MySql has no intersect directly, use full join on <=> item_id, item_quantity.

Comment: so like one join per item ?

Comment: Please provide sample data in Mysql consumable format to show it in action.

Comment: the tables format is not really yet defined, I showed my ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a query that first lists or groups elements as in your first example. Then select on that (as a subquery) grouping by basket and crating a string per basket through GROUP_CONCAT(). Then you can use those results (perhaps as another subquery) grouping by the group_concat string and having count(*) > 1 to find baskets with equal contents.

Comment: thanks, however that looks not efficient. Any way to search without comparing strings ?

Comment: @myquestionmysql I'd be surprised of anything that's substantially more efficient without being significantly more complicated. If your business logic requires doing this dozens of times a second (which would warrant looking for the most efficient solution), you'd benefit from using a maintained materialised view with an indexed summary in the form of an array in PostgreSQL.

Comment: no I don't need to use this 10s of times per second, if noone gives a better idea I will use this solution. Here is something based on your solution that works EXPLAIN SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(id_product) AS thegroup FROM `basket_item` GROUP BY id_basket HAVING thegroup = '1,1,2' However I think that once the table will be huge, that would take a lot of time ...